# Взаимодейтсвие Passport.js и Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, аутентификация

У меня есть приложение на Vue (localhost:8080) и приложение на Express (localhost:8081) с авторизацией (passport.js). Я понял, что passport сохраняет куки авторизации на localhost:8081, но я хочу проверять авторизован ли пользователь на клиенте.

- Вопрос 1: Как лучше это реализовать: пересылать cookie с сервера на
  клиент или есть другие варианты?
- Вопрос 2: Я получаю get с помощью axios с cookie на клиенте. Как из
  объекта AxiosResponce получить эти куки?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему следующим образом:
добавил в app.js заголовки

```
const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

и после этого в роутере Vue проверял авторизацию вот так

```
axios.get('url',{withCredentials:true})
```

и делал POST с логином следующим образом

```
axios.post('login',{withCredentials:true})
```

таким образом, куки можно передавать между хостами